# App crashes up on assigning something in onPostExecute method

Tags: java, android, json

As a beginner, I am following a lecture on JSON Demo (with exactly the same code and same version) of andriod studio. For some reason the app is crashing in the emulator whenever I add something in onPostExecute method.
For instance, it doesn't crash with following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

But it crashes when I add very basic to see the result in log like below:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("Website Content: ", result);

    }
```

I am not sure what's wrong here. I tried restarting the Android Studio for the sake RAM memory allocation, my internet is on, it debugs nicely in gradle console but gives this in android monitor:

```js
06-27 19:16:35.201 18116-18157/com.example.rushi.jsondemo V/RenderScript: 0xae53b000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask$override.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:44)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:0)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:30)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
06-27 19:16:35.396 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-27 19:16:35.411 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-27 19:16:35.411 18116-19529/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-27 19:16:35.451 18116-18116/com.example.rushi.jsondemo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-27 19:16:35.529 18116-18116/com.example.rushi.jsondemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.rushi.jsondemo, PID: 18116
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                                at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
                                                                                at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask$override.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:74)
                                                                                at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                                at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                                at com.example.rushi.jsondemo.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-27 19:19:47.263 18116-18122/com.example.rushi.jsondemo W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.513ms
06-27 19:21:35.896 18116-18116/com.example.rushi.jsondemo I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18116 SIG: 9
```

Here is my complete code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk");

    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i("Website Content: ", result);

        }

    }

}
```

Apologies for long post.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app crashes because the API returns nothing that because you haven't specified `API KEY` as document says
https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 , https://openweathermap.org/appid

Comment: oh yeah that makes sense. The URL was this https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02 which I had it incorrect.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your error basically complains about a null or empty string.
This your URL returns with a 401 error, which is explaining why you don't get that your string populated as expected. So to avoid crashes or errors like this, before your log try checking the String result for containing something.